# Is there a interactive filter tool when paging output?

Tags: command-line, pipe, filter, pager

I would like to take the output from a program and interactively filter which lines to pipe to the next command.

```
ls | interactive-filter | xargs rm
```

For example, I have a list of files that a pattern cannot match against to reduce. I would like a command `interactive-filter` that will page the output of the file list and I could interactively indicate which lines to forward to the next command. In this case each line would then be removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. [`iselect`](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/) provides an up-down list, (as input from a prior pipe), in which the user can tag multiple entries, (as output to the next pipe):

   ```
   # show some available executables ending in '*sh*' to run through `whatis`
   find /bin /sbin /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -name '*sh'   |
   iselect -t "select some executables to run 'whatis' on..." -a -m |
   xargs -d '\n' -r whatis
   ```

   Output after pressing the spacebar to tag a few on my system:

   ```
   dash (1)             - command interpreter (shell)
   ssh (1)              - OpenSSH SSH client (remote login program)
   mosh (1)             - mobile shell with roaming and intelligent local echo
   yash (1)             - a POSIX-compliant command line shell
   ```
2. [`vipe`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) allows interactively editing (with one's favorite text editor) what goes through a pipe.  Example:

   ```
   # take a list of executables with long names from `/bin`, edit that
   # list as needed with `mcedit`, and run `wc` on the output.
   find /bin -type f | grep '...............' | EDITOR=mcedit vipe | xargs wc
   ```

   Output (after deleting some lines while in `mcedit`):

   ```
      378   2505  67608 /bin/ntfs-3g.secaudit
      334   2250 105136 /bin/lowntfs-3g
      67    952  27152 /bin/nc.traditional
      126    877  47544 /bin/systemd-machine-id-setup
      905   6584 247440 total
   ```

Note on push & pull:

- `iselect` starts with a list in which *nothing* is selected.
- `vipe` starts with a list in which *every* item shown will be sent through the pipe, unless the user deletes it.

In *Debian*-based distros, both utils can be installed with `apt-get install moreutils iselect`.

Answer (score 4):

You can write `vipe` in a few lines of shell. Quick-and-dirty proof-of-concept that works for me:

```
EDITOR=vi   # change to preferred editor as needed.

vipe()
{
  cat > .temp.$$
  if $EDITOR .temp.$$ < /dev/tty > /dev/tty 2>&1 ; then
    cat .temp.$$
  fi
  rm .temp.$$
}
```

Source this into your shell and there it is. The purpose of the `if` is to suppress generation of the output if the editor (or attempt to run the editor) fails.